# Sublime Text basic comment highlighting

Tags: regex, sublimetext2

I switched from Notepad++ to Sublime bc using mac now. I just want to have // highlight the line in a different color, in the plain text "language". Essentially like a js comment, but I use it for headings and to organize my notes. This was easy with Notepad++ but I can't find what to edit with Sublime.

I've managed to edit the "Plain text.sublime-settings" file, example `"font_size": 20`to change font size. I would like to add a regex to make // highlight the line. How do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Plain text is just what it says - plain text. There is no capability to highlight "comments" or anything else, because comments don't exist in plain text. I'd suggest switching over to something like Markdown or reStructuredText so you can get syntax highlighting.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you can do this regex:

```
^//|\s//.*
```

Comment: Do you know what JSON properties I'd have to set in the settings file to go with that regex?

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to change the colour scheme of sublime text to change the colour of comments, then can I suggest the online sublime text theme editor http://tmtheme-editor.herokuapp.com/#/theme/Monokai

this great editor lets you create your own custom colour schemes or upload and edit existing ones.

Comment: I just want to add commenting ability to the Plain Text syntax.